# mostrar imagen GIF con jQuery

Tags: jquery

el siguiente codigo es para validar un logeo

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#login_a").click(function(){  
        $("#shadow").fadeIn("normal");  
         $("#login_form").fadeIn("normal");  
         $("#user_name").focus();  
    });  
    $("#cancel_hide").click(function(){  
        $("#login_form").fadeOut("normal");  
        $("#shadow").fadeOut();  
   });  
   $("#login").click(function(){  

        username=$("#user_name").val();  
        password=$("#password").val();  
         $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "login.php",  
            data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,  
            success: function(html){  
              if(html=='true')  
              {  
                $("#login_form").fadeOut("normal");  
                $("#shadow").fadeOut();  
                $("#profile").html("<a href='logout.php' id='logout'>Logout</a>");  

              }  
              else  
              {  
                    $("#add_err").html("Usuario o password incorrectos");  
              }  
            },  
            beforeSend:function()  
            {  
                 $("#add_err").html("Cargando...")  
            }  
        });  
         return false;  
    });  
});
```

En la linea

```
$("#add_err").html("Cargando...")
```

como puedo mostrar una imagen .gif en ves del mensaje de "Cargando..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu div puedes carga un elemento img con el gif

```
<div id="add_err">
<img src="nuestra_animacion.gif" />
</div>
//Es script después del ready
$('#add_err').hide();
//En la linea para mostrar tu mensaje de cargando lo cambiarías por esto
$('#add_err').fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: Gracias amigo funciono perfecto, otra duda si quisiera que el .gif se mueste sobre mi formulario como seria, porque ahorita se muestra abajo pero me gustaria que estuviera sobre los elemtos de mi formulario

Comment: Puedes ocupar la propiedad z-index de css por ejemplo
.clase{
z-index:99999999999;
}
Entre mas nueves tenga estará mucho mas en frente de los demás elementos